# What's the salary range of a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

How much would a typical Jedi Master earn (canon or Legends)?

Qui-gon Jinn had [image] on hand when he got stranded on Anakin's homeworld and that sounded like a lot, though I suppose it could've been a company credit card or the Queen's cash.

I am willing to accept an answer from any time period for which there's data, but it would probably make sense that such information would be most likely to exist when the Jedi were in full force and working for the pre-Palpatine Republic (i.e. there were a large number of Jedi living on a highly captialist world, and the Jedi's organization were likely receiving funding from a wealthy government).

Comment: I always figured that Qui-Gon's 20,000 credits was from Amidala and her entourage, rather than from his own stash.

Comment: @Thunderforge Could be. But I can think of a lot of times Jedi paid for for stuff and living in such a highly capitalistic society I think they'd have to get paid rather than pull off Star Trek style moneylessness/communism (but if I'm wrong, correct me). The Jedi also had service corps careers for Padawan wash outs and they got paid, so I imagine Jedi's made at least a living wage. Maybe akin to the wage of a solider?

Comment: You will give me $20,000 *waves hand*

Comment: There no indication that the money is Qui-Gon's. It's presumably whatever is in his expense account.

Comment: I've never seen any indication that Jedi were paid a salary. Money would be advanced when needed for expenses.

Comment: @TheMathemagician That's possible. I haven't read all of the books though or watched the cartoons, so I thought maybe someone more well-versed may have caught a detail relating to this.

Comment: Since when do monks get paid a salary?

Comment: @DVK-in-exile Well, while they aren't *Catholic* Monks, and Knights/warriors certainly get paid, even Catholic Monks receive an annual "budget" which is indistinguishable from an annual salary, and they even have to pay taxes (and websites exist for monks seeking to advance their private market careers whilst remaining monks).

Comment: Yet another illegitimate duplicate marking :P